# SQL Stored Procedure - Why use "OUT" while I can just SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetImmediateManager
   @employeeID INT,
   @managerID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT @managerID = ManagerID 
   FROM HumanResources.Employee 
   WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID
END
```

Hi guys, may I know the exact usage of "OUT"? How is it different with the below Stored Procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetImmediateManager
   @employeeID INT,
   @managerID INT 
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT @managerID = ManagerID 
   FROM HumanResources.Employee 
   WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID
END
```

Comment: You can execute the stored procedure with an output parameter without the OUTPUT keyword, but you won't be able to use the returned value in the calling program.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `SELECT ManagerID FROM HumanResources.Employee  WHERE EmployeeID = @employeeID`?  Without the output, your example does not return a value..

Comment: @SeeniVasan a... I think that pretty much solved my confusion.. Thx! :)

Comment: @jmoreno haha.. I just took one example from the msdn site and strip out the OUT word.. but thanks man.. I understood it better now after u mention about that :)

Answer (score 1):

For the answer go through the below link

(https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using output parameter procedure can return scalar output. Also when using parameter we can get `multiple output` from procedure.

If you use select to get the result, you need to store the result of procedure into a `dataset`, like DataTable in .NET

Generally, if your result is scalar, it is easier to use output parameter rather than result set.

Comment: Hi, thanks :) but can you explain a bit on the "scalar output" that you're saying. Please forgive me.. I'm a bit blur haha...

Comment: Scalar value means a simple data type, like a number or a string or data/time